# Java - Iterative deepening search with nodes

Tags: java, search

I'm in the process of designing a program that is meant to search through a two-dimensional array of numbers that represents a map for a path to a specified end point.  I've been using nodes that have several parameters, most prominently adjacent north, south, east, and west nodes each representing a square within the map.  The search method I'm currently trying to finish is with iterative deepening but every time I try running the program, I wind up with a stack overflow error.  This is the iterative deepening class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class IDeepeningSearch {
    private Node start;
    private Node end;
    private int[][] map;
    private ArrayList<Node> solution;

    //Build using file handler
    public IDeepeningSearch(String file){
        FileHandler handle = new FileHandler(file);

        //Create map
        map = handle.getMap();

        //Start node coordinates and value
        start = new Node();
        start.setRow(handle.getSRow());
        start.setCol(handle.getSCol());
        start.setValue(map[start.getRow()][start.getCol()]);

        //End node coordinates
        end = new Node();
        end.setRow(handle.getERow());
        end.setCol(handle.getECol());
        end.setValue(map[start.getRow()][start.getCol()]);
    }

    //Runs search
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
        solution = new ArrayList<Node>();
        //Value of i indicates depth to be explored; will increment with each failure
        while(solution.isEmpty()){
            search(start, i);
            i++;
        }
        if(!solution.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("It worked.");
        }
        System.out.println("If you're not seeing the other message then it failed.");
    }

    //Building tree
    public void build(Node head){
        setNLeaf(head);
        setSLeaf(head);
        setELeaf(head);
        setWLeaf(head);
//      if(head.getNorth() != null){
//          build(head.getNorth());
//      }
//      if(head.getSouth() != null){
//          build(head.getSouth());
//      }
//      if(head.getEast() != null){
//          build(head.getEast());
//      }
//      if(head.getWest() != null){
//          build(head.getWest());
//      }
    }

    //Performs search
    public void search(Node head, int depth){
        if(head.getRow() == end.getRow() && head.getCol() == end.getCol()){
            solution.add(head);
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(depth == 0){
                return;
            }
            build(head);
            if(head.getNorth() != null){
                search(head.getNorth(), depth--);
            }
            if(head.getSouth() != null){
                search(head.getSouth(), depth--);
            }
            if(head.getEast() != null){
                search(head.getEast(), depth--);
            }
            if(head.getWest() != null){
                search(head.getWest(), depth--);
            }
        }
    }

    //Sets north leaf
    public void setNLeaf(Node node){
        //Determines if parent is on edge of map and if desired space has 0 value
        if(node.getRow() != 0 && map[node.getRow() - 1][node.getCol()] != 0){
            Node n = new Node();
            n.setRow(node.getRow() - 1);
            n.setCol(node.getCol());
            n.setValue(map[n.getRow()][n.getCol()]);
            n.setParent(node);
            node.setNorth(n);
        }
    }

    //Sets south leaf
    public void setSLeaf(Node node){
        //Determines if parent is on edge of map and if desired space has 0 value
        if(node.getRow() != (map.length - 1) && map[node.getRow() + 1][node.getCol()] != 0){
            Node n = new Node();
            n.setRow(node.getRow() + 1);
            n.setCol(node.getCol());
            n.setValue(map[n.getRow()][n.getCol()]);
            n.setParent(node);
            node.setSouth(n);
        }
    }

    //Sets east leaf
    public void setELeaf(Node node){
        //Determines if parent is on edge of map and if desired space has 0 value
        if(node.getRow() != (map[0].length - 1) && map[node.getRow()][node.getCol() + 1] != 0){
            Node n = new Node();
            n.setRow(node.getRow());
            n.setCol(node.getCol() + 1);
            n.setValue(map[n.getRow()][n.getCol()]);
            n.setParent(node);
            node.setEast(n);
        }
    }

    //Sets west leaf
    public void setWLeaf(Node node){
        //Determines if parent is on edge of map and if desired space has 0 value
        if(node.getCol() != 0 && map[node.getRow()][node.getCol() - 1] != 0){
            Node n = new Node();
            n.setRow(node.getRow());
            n.setCol(node.getCol() - 1);
            n.setValue(map[n.getRow()][n.getCol()]);
            n.setParent(node);
            node.setWest(n);
        }   
    }
}
```

I thought I was doing this correctly but the errors I've been getting have been pretty constant.  This is what I wind up with.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Node.setSouth(Node.java:88)
at IDeepeningSearch.setSLeaf(IDeepeningSearch.java:113)
at IDeepeningSearch.build(IDeepeningSearch.java:48)
at IDeepeningSearch.search(IDeepeningSearch.java:75)
at IDeepeningSearch.search(IDeepeningSearch.java:77)
at IDeepeningSearch.search(IDeepeningSearch.java:80)
at IDeepeningSearch.search(IDeepeningSearch.java:77)
```

The second-to-last and last lines repeat.  I've tried building a full tree as well but that either gives me another stack overflow error or a null pointer exception.  I'm not really sure what the issue is here but if I can fix this, I'm sure I can finish my breadth-first search method as well.

Answer (score 1):

`depth--` evaluates to the original value of `depth`.  This means that the unmodified version of `depth` is being passed to the recursive call to `search()`, so your code is never approaching the base case.  Try `depth-1` instead.  Or, if you need the value of the local variable depth to change, `--depth`.

For example, this will continually print 10 until it reaches stack overflow

```
public void foo(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
    foo(x--);
}

foo(10);
```

Comment: I took your advice and changed it anyway but I think I may have found what the problem was.  I got an index out of bounds exception once I did that and I found that I unintentionally put the wrong check under setELeaf.  It was checking the position's ROW, not the column.  At any rate, it seems to be working now but I'll need to run a test or two to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The `StackOverflowError` is because of the flawed recursive calls of `search(node, depth--)` as Chris Rise has mentioned in his answer. Try `--depth` to fix this.

There is also poor memory management in this code, which is wasting heap memory that could either slow the program due to several calls to GC (Garbage-Collector) or lead to an `OutOfMemeoryError`! This problem is visible in the `setXLeaf(Node n)` methods (e.g. `setNLeaf(Node north)` etc.) where every time you are creating a `new Node`, while this can be done only when it's necessary with a simple check:

```
if (node.getSouth() == null) {
    Node n = new Node();
    n.setParent(node);
    node.setSouth(n);
}
node.getSouth().setRow(node.getRow() + 1);
node.getSouth().setCol(node.getCol());
node.getSouth().setValue(map[node.getRow() + 1][node.getCol()]);
```

This way you will avoid creating new objects that are unnecessary. This should be fixed in all the `setXLeaf(...)` methods.